# Como chamar outro aplicativo WP

Tags: windows-phone

Como faço para chamar outro aplicativo no próprio windows phone e na loja? (Como aplicativo do Facebook faz, chamando o messenger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo essa [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13496419/1608936), no WP7 não há nenhuma maneira eficaz de fazer isso, porem no WP8 é [possível](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769550(v=vs.105).aspx) e pode-se usar os [manipuladores de protocolo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) por meio do método [`launchUriAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx).

Por exemplo, se você quiser lançar o *app* de Configurações Wi-Fi pode fazer.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync("ms-settings-wifi")
```

Para lançar o Skype com um usuário selecionado você pode chamar:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync("skype:myskypeid");
```

Mais informações em: [URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Está dando erro. Tem como mandar um exemplo com um evento de um botão. O botão chama outro app.

Comment: @SeverinoJ.DaC.Neto Se possível crie uma outra pergunta especificando como você está fazendo isso e explicar qual o erro que está mostrando.

Comment: Já achei o erro, esqueci de colocar o método async. Vlw pela ajuda